# Width height by content height

Tags: html, css

Let I've a div block in which I'm specified a height as the follows:

```
<div>
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

And a styles:

```
div{
    height:100px;
}
```

But I want to do that if a content's height is more than `100px;` than I want to improve height of this `div` to a height of content. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use min-height for that.

Answer (score 2):

try like so

```
div{
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
div{
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you lose the height and just let it `float:left;` it will automaticaly change the height to the content